# Ffmpeg amix stopping

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am currently trying to overlay an audio file onto a video, so that the video's audio and the mp3's audio are merged. For this, I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0 output.mp4
```

The output I receive is the following:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.2 --enable-
shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-
hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --
host-ldflags= --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-
libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --
enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 500 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), 
yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 362 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 
tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, 
stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[mp3 @ 0x7f9a50861000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be 
inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from 'audio.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.19.100
  Duration: 00:03:13.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 192 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> amix:input0 (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (mp3) -> amix:input1 (graph 0)
  amix (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (aac)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7f9a4f00de00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7f9a4f00de00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast 
SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7f9a4f00de00] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x7f9a4f00de00] 264 - core 148 r2748 97eaef2 - H.264/MPEG-
4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html 
- options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex 
subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 
trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 
chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=11 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 
nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 
bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 
open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 
intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 
qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, 
stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), 
yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 
tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
```

After this, ffmpeg stops doing literally anything, except using nearly 100% of CPU (according to top). When using a larger video file, it starts to process but stops right before the end (at around 90%). I am using ffMpeg 3.3.2, the same command works nicely in ffMpeg 2.6.8. When researching, I found this request from June 2017:

http://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2017-June/036323.html

The problem described there is pretty much the same that I experience, but there seems to be no feedback there.

I would like to fix this problem asap. Any recommendations?

**Edit:** As requested, I've included the log with `-v 48`-flag. Since it's too long to include in this answer, I've uploaded it to PasteBin: https://pastebin.com/r0Ta5Tb9

Comment: Run the command with `-v 48` and paste the log. There will be more details.

Comment: I've added a PasteBin. Seems to be a problem with "cur_dts is invalid", at least this is what I get from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a fix for this hanging behaviour, committed on Jun 18 2017. See bug ticket [6424](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6424). So, upgrade to a current git version and check.

Some people report the patch not working for them. In which case, the workaround is to insert the asetnsamples filter.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex [0]asetnsamples=8192[a];[1]asetnsamples=8192[b];[a][b]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0 output.mp4
```

P.S. The dts messages relate to the video stream.

Comment: With your command, I am getting "Filter asetnsamples has an unconnected output". I am no mastermind regarding ffmpeg. Can you help me out?

Comment: Rerun the command with -report and share that log.

Comment: I've added quotes around the filter_complex and now I get another error: "Error marking filters as finished" and after that "Conversion failed!". See: https://pastebin.com/nUVWnsEv

Comment: You should upgrade and test the fix first. This is a symptom of the same bug.